# How set a url(callback) to listen a answer by javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, callback, asynccallback

Currently, I am consuming a rest service that has a signature

```
http://service.ip/auth?clien=xx&redirect=URIXX
```

where **URIXXX** shall be

```
  http://localhost:8080/auth/callback
```

I wonder if it is possible to open a "URIXXX" in a javascript in order to received the answer from the server? Like a callback?

Comment: you can do that, by extracting the url value, and then using ajax.

Comment: I am new in javascript do you have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the scripts employs `JSONP` then yes, otherwise declare a `HTTPRequest` and then parse then extra stuff out of the return and inject the contents into the head of your document in a wrapper function which opens a window indicated and the writes the needful scripts / content into the newly created window...

If you mean you are trying to tell your request to go to another location for the response I would suggest you check out my WebServer Class which supports Comet style interactions...

https://net7ntcip.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/89621#1752948

After you submit the request you can then receive in the response the location to addition to a token... You can take this token and send it to the page indicated in the response and then you will have achieved what you wanted to do..

I suppose the same technique could be employed to do the same thing without my web server...